# Wired internet connection keeps dropping on Ubuntu 18.04 VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-10.04

So basically I set up LAMP stack on my PC with Virtual Box and Ubuntu 18.04 VM. Configured everything and it was working just fine for like a month now until it just randomly started dropping connection 2 days ago - working for a couple of minutes at best and then end up being down. I had the same issue when a year ago I installed full Ubuntu on separate HDD on the same PC so it had nothing to do with Windows 10 one. I'm pretty much a linux newbie and haven't a single clue where to begin fixing.

I tried disabling IPv6, setting IP address to static and reverting it back to dynamic, rebooting, manually disabling the connection and enabling it again. Everything fixes it only for a short period of time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah but I'm having issues with wired connection tho :/